# Set a timer before executing code in MKMapViewDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, mapkit, mkmapview

Using a MKMapView, I want to catch the moment the user finished to move the map to another region, to then display annotations in this area.

To catch the moment he finished to move the Map I use :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool){
}
```

However I would time to add a time lapse of 1s before the code inside the delegate is called, in case the user starts to move the camera a bit more. And if the user moves the Map again before the end of this time lapse it cancels the execution of the code of course.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a `DispatchWorkItem`, an object that encapsulates some code to perform later. You can cancel the work item when the user starts moving the map view again in the `mapView(_:regionWillChangeAnimated:)` method:

```swift
class YourClass: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    private var userFinishedMovingMapViewWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionWillChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        // Cancel any previous work item
        userFinishedMovingMapViewWorkItem?.cancel()
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        // Create a new work item, store it in a property, and set it to execute
        // on the main queue after one second from now
        let workItem = DispatchWorkItem(qos: .userInteractive) {
            // Code you want to execute after 1 second
        }

        userFinishedMovingMapViewWorkItem = workItem
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: workItem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a timer :

```
var delayTimer:Timer? = nil
```

then write these methods:

```
private func stopDelayTimer(){
    self.delayTimer?.invalidate()
    self.delayTimer = nil
}

private func startDelayTimer(timeIntervalInSecond : Int){
    self.stopDelayTimer()

    delayTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:TimeInterval(timeIntervalInSecond),target:self,selector:#selector(onDelayTimeOut), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc fileprivate func onDelayTimeOut(){
        //do Your  work here
}
```

call start from your delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool){
self.startDelayTimer(timeIntervalInSecond: 1)
}
```

**onDelayTimeOut()** will get called after your provided timeInterval

Answer (score 1):

Create a property for `URLSessionDataTask` type and call `cancel` method in the map view delegate method

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var task: URLSessionDataTask?

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool){
        task?.cancel()
        perform(#selector(fetchDetails), with: self, afterDelay: 1.0)
    }

    @objc func fetchDetails() {

        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "yourURL")!)
        task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

        })
        task?.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this alternative, only I don't need to make an URLRequest, only to fetch data in an array. Do you have an alternative ?